# Regex pattern for getting part of a string

Tags: c#, regex, poker

Hi I have strings like:

```
** Dealing Flop ** [ As, 4s, 8h ]
** Dealing Turn ** [ 4h ]
** Dealing River ** [ 3s ]
```

I need know is it flop turn or river and what cards has been dealt.
for now I have

```
new Regex(@"^\*\* Dealing (?<flop>F)|(?<turn>T)|(?<river>R)");
```

and what i need should be something like

```
new Regex(@"^\*\* Dealing (?<flop>F)|(?<turn>T)|(?<river>R)*[(?<cards>)]$");
```

but it does not work.
Please help.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Surely this would be a lot more readable by using `.Contains()`?

```
enum Situation {
 Flop, 
 Turn,
 River
}

Situation GetSituation(string input){
 if(input.Contains("Flop"){ return Situation.Flop;}
 if(input.Contains("Turn"){ return Situation.Turn;}
 if(input.Contains("River"){ return Situation.River;}
 throw new ArgumentException("Invalid situation");
}
```

You can get the played hands like this:

```
var start = myString.IndexOf("[");
var end = myString.IndexOf("]");
var hands = myString.SubString(start, (end - start)).Split(",");
```

Comment: I need a regex to do it as it is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you want check if in the string there is Dealing Flop/River or Turn you can use this regex

```
(.*Dealing Flop| Dealing Turn| Dealing River.*)
```

And then you can extract from string all data that you need.
But sincerely I prefer @JeroenVannevel method because it's more clear and simply to understand

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern to know the situation and the cards:

```
\b(?<ftr>Flop|Turn|River) \*\* \[ (?<c1>[^], ]+)(?>, (?<c2>[^], ]+))?(?>, (?<c3>[^] ]+))? ]
```